# What version of the protestant Bible was familiar in Germany around 1880?

Tags: history, book

Records in the niedersächsisches Landesarchiv show the mathematician Richard Dedekind was specific about how he wanted a certain aphorism of his reported.  He had given it in 1878 and he wanted it reported as

„Wir sind göttlichen Geschlechtes und besitzen ohne jeden Zweifel schöpferische Kraft nicht blos in materiellen Dingen (Eisenbahnen, Telegraphen), sondern ganz besonders in geistigen Dingen."

He specifically objected to putting „Natur" in place of  „Geschlechtes" but he gave no further reason for this.

The quote is an obvious alteration of  Apostelgeschichte (Acts) 17:29 and I would like to figure out which other changes Dedekind made.  You might think this is an easy question--just compare Dedekind's words to the original.  But it is not easy because at least two relevantly different versions occurred in the Luther bible in the first place.

While the reference to railroads and telegraphs is obviously not in Luther it echoes what is in some but not all of Luther's translations.  In the 1522 first version Luther wrote of  „menschlichen kunst vnnd tichtung."  His final 1545 bible version reduces that to „menschliche gedancken."

You can imagine the difference of „kunst vnnd tichtung" from  „gedancken" would make a difference to German materialists in the line of Ludwig Feuerbach, for example.

It may be impossible to ever find what Dedekind had in mind, but who knows what further information may lurk in the niedersächsisches Landesarchiv?  I would like some orientation on what sources were likely familiar to Dedekind in 1878.

To forestall misunderstanding I am not asking how Luther *should* have translated the passage or what it really means, or whether Dedekind was inspired by either the Holy Ghost or Feuerbach in making his changes.   If anyone happens to know documentation showing Dedekind read Feuerbach that would be interesting but probably no one does.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: http://christianity.stackexchange.com

Comment: @HubertSchölnast That site is for "for committed Christians, experts in Christianity and those interested in learning more."  I am not trying to learn anything about Christianity, but about a noted piece of German literature.

Comment: I don’t think this question is really on-topic on [christianity.SE]. However, I’m not sure whether it is on-topic here, either.

Comment: You need to accept there were a pretty large amount of different versions / revisions of the original Luther translations around in the 19th century. Nearly every publisher had their own, and there were many of them. That was actually the main reason why there was a movement to replace those with an *official* version in the late 19th century. Apart from that, there were re-translations as pointed out in guidot's answer. I pretty much doubt your question can be answered with certainty. ...

Comment: ...I happen to have two late 1800 bibles that claim to be the "Lutherbibel" traduced through different arms of my family, nicely illustrated, but both slightly different in translation and orthography.

Comment: I'd say this is a question about historical text. The text being a Bible doesn't make it about Christianity. In this question, it's "just another old book".

Comment: @tofro Could you tell me if your late 1800 bibles start Apostelgeschichte 17:29 with "So wir denn göttlichs Geschlechts sind"? Or how do they start it?

Comment: You seem to have some misconceptions. The above quote is perfectly understandable to a German speaker today (except possibly for the meaning of “Geschlecht”), only the orthography is unusual.

Comment: @CarstenS Of course it is understandable.  Why would I doubt that?

Comment: "it is not clear what he meant by his version": Even finding the very Bible that Dedekind possessed would not help you. This isn't just a version of a Bible verse. He only referenced a rather popular verse to justify the assumption that men are of divine descent. From there on he concludes that we are, like god, creators, and that we are creative with our minds ("And God _said_, Let there be light: and there was light.")

Comment: @Matthias My experience in publishing on historical issues like this is that you do not know what will help, until you try.  If you want to discuss the interpretive issues of this quote you can e-mail me.  But that would be off-topic for this list.

Comment: I would like to explain why this question is considered off-topic here: It's neither about the German language nor about German literature. It's about arcane details of translations of a book that most German speakers are not obsessed about in the way that some Americans are. (As in: professing to take every word literally, though in practice they are extremely selective about what they treat this way.) Also, in German it is absolutely standard to carefully update the language used in literary works (even the classics) with each major edition.

Comment: That said, I think the real problem is probably that Dedekind cited the bible extremely freely - or rather, improvised on it -, rather than relying slavishly on some specific translation of this sentence. The parenthetic mention of railroads and telegraphs shows that he didn't try to disguise this.

Comment: @HansAdler  Obviously he changed the point of the verse. That is why I say so in the question. The question is: was he deliberately changing it or did he think he was just expanding it?  You think he deliberately changes the subject from icons to railroads and telegraphs.  But he may think he is simply glossing the Greek words ''technes kai enthumeseos" omitted from some but not all Luther bibles.   This is a question about Richard Dedekind's use of a landmark text in German literature.  But people who insist it is a question of christian theology will certainly take it off topic.

Answer (score 4):

I have a Luther bible that belongs to my family, printed 1885 in Berlin (in Fraktur). It says

> Stereotyp-Ausgabe der preußischen Haupt-Bibelgesellschaft. Berlin, Klosterstr. 71

I have no idea how representative this edition was for "university educated protestants".

Apostelgeschichte 17.29 reads:

> So wir denn göttlichen Geschlechts sind; sollen wir nicht meinen, die Gottheit sei gleich den goldenen, silbernen und steinernen Bildern, durch menschliche Gedanken gemacht.

(There's really a semicolon after the first phrase.)

Personally, I'd consider "wir sind göttlichen Geschlechtes" to be a literal reference. The difference between "Geschlechtes" and "Geschlechts" is a matter of style and diction and isn't important in any way.

Comment: The *Evangelische Haupt-Bibelgesellschaft Berlin* goes back to the *Preußische Haupt-Bibelgesellschaft* in Berlin, and was officially recognized (landesherrliche Anerkennung erhielt) in Prussia in 1814. It was of course protestant. This history, plus the fact that it uses Luther's 1545 version with just minor reform to the spelling, suggests it was highly suitable for university educated people.

Answer (score 3):

Meyers Konversationslexikon from 1885-92 states under "Bibelübersetzung"

> [ Die Lutherübersetzung hat sich ] bis heute fast unangefochten behauptet. Unter den Versuchen, dieselbe durch neue Arbeiten oder Umgestaltungen zu ersetzen, kommen besonders in Betracht die Leistungen von De Wette (Heidelb. 1809-12, 6 Bde.; 4. Aufl. 1858, 3 Bde.), Stier (nach dem berichtigten Text von J. F. v. Meyer; 3. Aufl., Bielef. 1869), Bunsen (fortgeführt von Kamphausen und Holtzmann, Leipz. 1858-65, 9 Bde.), bezüglich des Neuen Testaments insonderheit die Protestantenbibel, herausgegebenen P. W. Schmidt (Neues T., das. 1872-1873; 3. Aufl. 1879), und die Übersetzung von Weizsäcker (1875, 2. Aufl. 1882).

Comment: And Meyer on that page says the Bibelanstalt von Canstein, from 1845 to 1855, put out a 7 volume comparative text of Luther's many versions, because even Luther's final 1545 version was "kaum noch den Gelehrten bekannten."